# Why am I getting a warning about uninitialized variables in this perl script?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm very new to Perl and I'm adapting someone else's script to parse a log file from a device. Ignoring any weirdness earlier in the script, the problem I have is when it gets to the last print statements in the for loop. Instead of printing any variables, I get a warning if I "use warnings": Use of uninitialized variable on lines 34 and 35. None of the variables are initialized, but I don't understand why. They're being initialized before the for loop. What's going on here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my $datafile = 'router-tcam-acl-out.log';
open DATAFILE, "<$datafile" or die "$datafile: $!";
my @data = <DATAFILE>;
close DATAFILE;
chomp @data;

print @data;

my ($dest_ip, $src_ip, $dest_port, $src_port, $tcp_flags, $protocol, $tos, $dest_mask, $src_mask, $result, $hit_cnt);

foreach my $data (@data) {
    if ($data =~ /^_V_\S+\s+(\S+,)\s+(\S+)\s+P=(\S+)\s+P=(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+) /) {
            $dest_ip=$1;
            $src_ip=$2;
            $dest_port=$3;
            $src_port=$4;
            $tcp_flags=$5;
            $protocol=$6;
            $tos=$7;
            next;
        }
        elsif ($data =~ /_M \S+ (\S+) (\S+) /) {
            $dest_mask=$1;
            $src_mask=$2;
            next;
        }
        elsif ($data =~ /rtr\_rslt_(\S+) hit_cnt=(\S+) /) {
            $result=$1;
            $hit_cnt=$2
        }
        print "\n$src_ip,$src_mask,$src_port,$dest_ip,$dest_mask,$dest_port";
        print ",$protocol,$tos,$result,$hit_cnt";
        }
```

Comment: Well take a look at your first if statement. What if it fails, what does happen ? Will **all** those variables get assigned ?

Comment: Those variables are declared before the loop, not initialized. Their value is `undefined` until you assign any value to them.

Comment: The variables are only initialised in the if statements, so if `$data` does not match then various of the fields will not be initialised when the `print` statements are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my ($dest_ip, $src_ip, $dest_port, $src_port, $tcp_flags, $protocol, $tos, $dest_mask, $src_mask, $result, $hit_cnt);
```

This *declares* the variables, it doesn't *initialize* them.  I'm not sure if in perl there's an easier way than `my ($x, $y, ...) = (0, 0, ...)` or splitting it into lines, `my $x = 0; my $y = 0; ...`

Comment: Yep, I had a total brain cloud there. I don't know why I was thinking that "my" also initialized the variables instead of just declaring them and setting the scope.